# substring of PHP var inside JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use the substring method inside JavaScript code which echoes some PHP variable but it does not work.

```
$('#tarif_public_total').val( <?php echo $_tarif_public; ?> * $('#tarif_public').val() )

u=$('#tarif_membre').val()* <?php echo $_tarif_membre; ?> + $('#tarif_public').val()* <?php echo $_tarif_public; ?>
uu=u.substring(0,6)

$('#total_total').val(uu)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `parseInt()` on all the instances of `val()` (like Gert G suggested) you have to do:

```
uu=("" + u).substring(0,6)
```

or:

```
uu=String(u).substring(0,6)
```

Since you can't use substring on numbers. You have to cast back to a string using `("" + var)`

[**Live demo of ("" + var)**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8nHD/)

Comment: `String(var)` is not the preferred way to cast to a string, `(""+var)` is better and faster.

Comment: I am using this on a text input where the user can increment or decrement the text input value but how do you shift the coma? (im using decimal values)

Comment: @tada Coma? For the hundreds and thousands separators? or decimal point style? I'd start by looking at: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/formatnumber.shtml & http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html